# Hibernate the computer from C#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I want to Hibernate my computer by clicking on a button in C# Windows Forms Application.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Hibernate the computer
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Application.SetSuspendState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setsuspendstate(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.SetSuspendState(PowerState.Hibernate, true, true);
}
```

Or:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
Process.Start("shutdown", "/h /f");
```

Answer (score 3):

See [`Application.SetSuspendState()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setsuspendstate(v=vs.110).aspx) method for more information.

You can call it like

```
Application.SetSuspendState(PowerState.Hibernate, true, true)
```